# Measures which are invariant under a group action are unique

Tags: group-actions, geodesic, borel-measures

I am reading about geodesic currents on surfaces, which are measures on the space of geodesic curves on the surface.

The authors use a result that since a particular measure is invariant under a group  action, it is unique up to a scalar. However I cannot find any such result in the literature. Does this result exist?

Here's a specific example, from "Hyperbolic structures on surfaces and geodesic
currents" by Aramayona-Leiniger, pg 29:

"Even without the specific expression for L used in the proof, it is easy to see that $L(E_\delta)$ is a fixed constant multiple of \delta. For this, note that since L is invariant under the action of the entire isometry group of $\mathbb{H}^2$, $\delta\to L(E_\delta)$ defines a measure on any geodesic, and this measure is invariant under any isometry. ***Therefore, it is a constant multiple of the Lebesgue (length) measure.*** Because PSL$(2,\mathbb{R})$ acts transitively on the set of geodesics, the constant is independent of the geodesic."

I don't understand why we can say it is some multiple of the Lesbesgue measure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Welcome to the site.  You can use LaTeX-like [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) formatting here.  Also, it would be nice if you'd include a citation of the paper or book where you're reading this.

Comment: Look for Haar measures.